# Two sample test on mostly independent samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a sample dataset of semi-finals of a swimming competition and there are multiple categories in which swimmers can participate. I want to do a hypothesis test (two-sample) on this to check if the result time differs in different categories.

But in the sample there are some swimmers who participated in more than one category, how am I supposed to handle this? Is a paired t-test the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither paired nor unpaired t-tests are appropriate if some of the data points are paired and some are not.  The paired test drops data from swimmers who only swim in one category, while the unpaired ignores the pairing. This can be handled in a linear mixed model with separate intercept terms for each swimmer, e.g., using the `lme4` package for R:

```r
your_model = lmer(time ~ 1 + category + (1|swimmer_id), data = your_data)
```